# ArrayAdapter in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have this below code and this `ListActivity` does not work , all things I know that I'm sure problem comes from my array, when I use from arrays with this format `String aaaa = {"...","somthing"};` It works! But I need to use a format like my code shows 
 what is wrong ?

```
public class ff extends ListActivity {

private String[] aaaa;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorite_test);
    setListAdapter(new AA());

    aaaa = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        aaaa[i] = "string" + i;
    }

}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ff.this, TestActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}


class AA extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public AA() {

        super(ff.this, R.layout.games_list_layout, aaaa);

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games_list_layout, parent, false);
        }

        return row;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the adapter after inserting the values into the array? Like calling setListAdapter right below your for loop

Comment: sry i dont know what u say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you are doing wrong is, you haven't initialized `String[] aaaa` Array. So Initialize it before Using it in ArrayAdpater.

```
setContentView(R.layout.favorite_test);
aaaa = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    aaaa[i] = "string" + i;
}
setListAdapter(new AA());
```

Comment: You should accept the answer if it helps you to solved your problem.